# Datatable Export - Titulo Problema

Tags: jquery, excel, datatables, exportar

Buenas noches mi duda es la siguiente

Estoy usando datatables para realizar la carga de un listado en una table y tambien estoy usando la propiedades de exportacion. Para este ultimo es que tengo inconvenientes, lo que sucede es que no quiero que me aparezca el titulo en la primera fila de la hoja de mi documento de excel exportado.

```
//este codigo me imprime en la primera fila el titulo y es lo que no quiero
dom: 'Bfrtip',
buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'excel',
        text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Exportar a Excel',
        title: 'Mi Titulo',
    }
],
```

```
//Use este codigo en reemplazo, me soluciona el problema pero me genera otro
//Que es el de la imagen, no tengo problemas al recuperar, porque me muestra
//todos los datos sin excepcion, pero es tedioso para el usuario tener que 
//abrir el archivo y salga siempre ese mensaje
dom: 'Bfrtip',
buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'excel',
        text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Exportar a Excel',
        filename: 'Mi Titulo',
        title: ''
    }
],
```

Viendo el problema se encuentra en el atributo **'title'**, asi le pongan comillas vacias o valor igual a null, persiste este problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas Noches.

Gracias por la colaboración.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He cambiado la versión de los archivos de **datatable** que estaba usando, y se soluciono el inconveniente, veo que generalmente es un problema de versiones de **buttons**.

Pero espero se pueda solucionar sin tener que cambiar toda la versión de los archivos.